# Understanding Java methods

Tags: java, methods

So, I'm very new to Java, I have a summer college course and we're on functions or methods and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding them.

There is a question on a lab I'm having a little trouble with:

> "Write a method called MaxOfThree that accepts three integer
>   parameters and returns the largest of the three."

This is what I have so far but I'm not sure whats wrong.  I added the print statement at the end because I wasn't getting a return value when I ran it but now I'm getting errors and it's not compiling.  If you could help me understand methods a bit more I'd greatly appreciate it.  For instance how the parameters work and calling it and if what's included in the function call is correct and how that works.  I just get so confused when I read through the material and was hoping for an explanation in more layman's terms.  Thanks for any help, here is what I have so far.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 2, b = 3, c = 4;
        int maxValue = max3(a, b, c);
    }

    public static int max3(int a, int b, int c) {
        int max = a;
        if (b > max) max = b;
        if (c > max) max = c;
        return max;
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Here are the errors I'm receiving just in case...

```
Test.java:16: error: unreachable statement
           System.out.println(max);
           ^
Test.java:17: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
2 errors
```

Comment: Oh I forgot, here are the errors I'm receiving just in case...    Test.java:16: error: unreachable statement
      System.out.println(max);
      ^
Test.java:17: error: missing return statement
   }
   ^
2 errors

Comment: The method will exit once it reaches the `return` statement. So, the `println` won't be executed.

Comment: As a matter of style, I think it would be better to put the println inside the main method rather than in your max3 method.

Comment: Agreed. Once you get a value returned to `maxValue` add your println() statement after. You would need to change the variable name as well  `System.out.println(maxValue);`

Comment: So, other than the print statement I created the method correctly?  Seeing as how I kinda of got a little lucky on that Can you explain exactly how the function is working?  Also, I take it return max does not actually show you the max int of the three ints when you run it?  For that I need the print statement?

Comment: I understand you're new to this, but did you try to search for "`error: unreachable statement`"? There are already multiple questions about this error on StackOverflow. Did you really not find anything to put you on the right track in any of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest You to change those `if` statements into one simple `for` loop with simple `int[]` vector. This solution is much more elegant and flexible. Additionally, You initialized and not used anywhere `int maxValue = max3(a, b, c);` in Your code.

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] numbers = new int[] {2, 3, 4};

        System.out.println(maxValue(numbers));
    }

    public static int maxValue(int[] n) {
        int max = n[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < n.length; i++) {
            if (n[i] > max) {
                max = n[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

But let's bow for a moment on the problem of methods implementation in Java.

At the begining of Your journey through the vastness of the Java realm You should get familiar with two types of methods: 1) **void methods**, and 2) **return methods**. The first ones are responsible for doing something without returning any value. We can for example use them for setting values of the fields of our application, initializing GUI, or other operations. The use of the **void method** can look like this:

```
/* method declaration */
void setValue(int value) {
    someField = value;
}

/* method invocation */
setValue(5);
```

After invocation of `setValue(5)` the value of the `someField` object will be `5`. However, you have to remember about type compatibility, so in this case `someField` can not be e.g of `String` type.

Second method type mentioned above, i.e **return method** is very useful, when you expect the method to give You an output, e.g in result of some operations conducted on the data You've given to Your method. But of course it's not necessary, to provide for the **return method** an input. Anyway, the use of **return method** can look like this:

```
/* method returns text You've given to it */
String getText(String text) {
    return text;
}

/* method returns result of addition of three given int's */
int calculate(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a + b + c;
}

/* method return a random number */
int createRandomNumber() {
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt();
}
```

You can easily see, that there is plenty of space for improvisation. Basicaly and in summary, **void methods** can work with given objects, for example can set values and conduct other operations, but thay don't return any STRAIGHT results You can work with. **Return methods**, from the other hand, provide You physical results, which You can use in further operations, or even in other methods, for example:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Demo {

    private static int someValue;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        setValue(calculate(
        createRandomNumber(), 
        createRandomNumber(), 
        createRandomNumber()));

        System.out.println(someValue);
    }

    public static void setValue(int value) {
        someValue = value;
    }

    public static int calculate(int a, int b, int c) {
        return a + b + c;
    }

    public static int createRandomNumber() {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: bluevoxel --  Isn't that where the method is being called (int maxValue = max3(a, b, c);)?

Comment: Yep. You initialized `maxValue` object and use nowhere.

Comment: Accepted answer with negative score? +1

Answer (score 4):

You can't have a statement after the return statement, or to be more exact - a statement imediatelly after a return statement (such as your println) can never be executed, and is therefore an error.

The println should be before the return statement.

```
    public static int max3(int a, int b, int c) {
       int max = a;
       if (b > max) max = b;
       if (c > max) max = c;
       System.out.println(max);
       return max;
    }
```

Comment: Not a good way of putting it.  You _could_ have statements after the _return_, if the _return_ were somehow conditional.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put

```
System.out.println(max);
```

before:

```
return max;
```

the reason is your `return` unconditionally ends the function and therefore the compiler won't reach the `println` causing a compile error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the compiler detects that execution will never reach the `System.out.println` line, so it refuses to compile.  The line `return max;` effectively ends the method, so nothing more will run after that.

You should move `return max;` to below the `System.out.println` line.

Answer (score 2):

Swap your last 2 lines (`return` and `System`).

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this, `return max` statement should be the last line in your method if you want to print something, because `return` statement goes back or invoke the line that called him,so your print statement is not reach.

```
 public static int max3(int a, int b, int c) {
           int max = a;
           if (b > max) max = b;
           if (c > max) max = c;
           System.out.println(max);
           return max;
        }
```

Comment: Wow you guys are fast!  Thanks for all of the help, I'm gonna read through all the comments and see if I still have questions.

Comment: What I'm a little unclear about is when calling the function why I need maxValue?  I kinda just added that because of other methods I've seen.  Why isn't (like python) I'm just calling the method like this...max3(a, b, c);?  Why do I need a new (variable) I guess?

Comment: actually you can have `System.out.println(max3(a, b, c))` , and the `maxValue` is more useful, when you want to use it to other line of your codes.

Comment: Meaning what though?  Is that what maxValue is doing essentially, creating a new variable for the function max3, that can then be used in other areas of a program as a variable with the value of the max3 function?  Could I not call the max3 function in other areas of a program without maxValue?

Comment: Yes you can call the function,but its more maintainable, imagine typing this in everywhere you want it`(max3(a, b, c)` than `maxValue`, also waht if you want to do something on your `maxValue` like `maxValue` * 3? if you are not using a new variable, you have go to all your lines of code with this `max3(a, b, c) * 3`, its messy and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `System.out.println()` statement after the `return`. `return` ends the method and so the `System.out.println()` will never happen because the method will have ended. That's why you are getting errors. Put the `System.out.println()` before the `return`:

```
public static int max3(int a, int b, int c) {
       int max = a;
       if (b > max) max = b;
       if (c > max) max = c;
       System.out.println(max);
       return max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the code you provided is that you're trying to print to the console, after you use your return statement.  This causes your program to never reach that line: `System.out.println(max);`

Comment: What I'm a little unclear about is when calling the function why I need maxValue?  I kinda just added that because of other methods I've seen.  Why isn't (like python) I'm just calling the method like this...max3(a, b, c);?  Why do I need a new (variable) I guess?

Comment: Any chance someone could explain how the method and parameters are working a little more clearly for me?  I'm a little confused by the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As already been said, after you return something, the method will end. So your output in the last line of the method will not be executed, so remove it.
You can print the returned value of the method when you write the following outside of the method:

```
System.out.println("highest value:" + max3(a,b,c));
```

So now, the 3 values are given to the method which can do something with them now. After it did the calculations, the method returns a value, which can now be printed to the console for example.